# jquery ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I'm trying to use the [JQuery CKEditor plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/CKEditor/#tab-Overview). I downloaded the [.zip archive](http://jquery-ckeditor-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CKEditor.zip), but when I open the `index.html` page therein, the editor is not displayed in the demo page, so I guess there's something missing from this archive or I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages in the console?

Comment: Why are you using a separate plugin? CKEditor comes with Javascript support.

Comment: @Pekka No errors in the console

Comment: @Purmou I'm using the JQuery plugin, because I want to the able to interact with the CKEditor using JQuery

Comment: @Don: What do you mean by "interact?"

Comment: @Purmou I want to be able to use the simplified API provided by the JQuery plugin

Comment: CKEditor already provides its own jQuery adapter: http://nightly.ckeditor.com/latest/ckeditor/_samples/jqueryadapter.html

Comment: @AlfonsoML that's the one I'm referring to

Comment: No, that's not the same. You have linked to a jQuery plugin, but I've provided you a link to test the jQuery adapter created by the CKSource team. You can read more about it here: http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_for_jQuery

Comment: Did you try to put your folder in a webserver instead of opening it directly from your file system ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you still have to install the [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) in addition to the code in that ZIP file. Install it and set the `path` at the top of the "jquery.CKEditor.js" file so that plugin knows where CKEditor is.

Comment: Is this installation process documented somewhere?

Comment: It depends on which version of CKEditor you want. For the free version [here](http://ckeditor.com/download), the installation instructions are [here](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Installation).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor

and it has all the information needed. for toolbar configuration this post might help:

[Rails 3.1 ckeditor: Adding fontsize in toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425318/rails-3-1-ckeditor-adding-fontsize-in-toolbar/9754699#9754699)