# Rails 3.1 ckeditor: Adding fontsize in toolbar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ckeditor

I have ckeditor in my rails 3.1 app but I am not able to add fontsize and font dropdowns to my  toolbar.

My edit view code:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "ckeditor/ckeditor.js" %>
...
<%= form_for @page, :html => { :class => 'edit_page', :id => "page_form" } do |page| %>
...
<%= page.cktext_area :content, {:height => "350px", :width => "920px"}%>
...
<% end %>
```

I am able to adjust the height and width but not add any other parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be late but in `rails 3.1` app you can go to `/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/ckeditor-3.7.0/vendor/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js` this is where configuration for the toolbars takes place.

Here is an exemple of my configuration

```
    ..
    ...
     /* Toolbars */
      config.toolbar = 'Easy';

      config.toolbar_Easy =
        [
            ['Source','-','Preview'],
            ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord',],
            ['Undo','Redo','-','SelectAll','RemoveFormat'],
            ['Styles','Format','FontSize'],['Maximize','-','About'],
            ['Subscript', 'Superscript', 'TextColor'],
            ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike'], ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','Blockquote'],
            ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
            ['Link','Unlink','Anchor'],
          /*   ['Image', 'Attachment', 'Flash', 'Embed'], */
            ['Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak']
        ];
    ...
    ..
```

and there is an image of how this configuration looks in a form

[image: ckeditor modified toolbar]

Answer (score 1):

I never used this gem or ckeditor before, but looking at their documentation it seems pretty straight forward.

Looks like you just modify public/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js

```
config.fontSize_sizes = '16/16px;24/24px;48/48px;';
```

Ref.

https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor

http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.fontSize_sizes

Comment: ya i tried that, but I think the file that is being used is not the one I am changing. It is taking assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js which is minified and I couldn't find it inside my code base diretory. Any help on that? And where it could be? I searched assests folder inside my code dir..

Answer (score 1):

You can install this plugin http://ckeditor.com/addon/font

Extract and copy the "font" folder to `ckeditor/plugins` directory then inside your code call the plugin.

```
CKEDITOR.replace(this.id, {
    extraPlugins: 'font',
});
```

Now your toolbar will show up with font family and size option as below

[image: font-family and fontsize in ckeditor]

Answer (score 0):

rmagnum2002, Is it possible to change the width and height of the toolbar button. ex: changing width of size drop down box.

I have added some plugins and but dont' know how to change width of the plugin?